# When I deploy to Heroku, my deployment is successful but my .glb file receives 404 error

Tags: javascript, heroku, three.js, vite

As title states, whenever I deploy my app, the entire three.js project deploys perfectly but my .glb file receives the 404 resource not found error. I’m not sure what the issue is. I’ve tried to change the file path but no success. I am using Vite.js for local running

Github repo - https://github.com/ElijahSchrock/Neo-Runner

Heroku Deploy - https://neo-runner.herokuapp.com/

[Here is my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMArV.jpg)

[Here is my create character function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0GZ4.jpg)

Here is Don McCurdy's take on it from the threejs forum
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/when-i-deploy-to-heroku-my-deployment-is-successful-but-my-glb-file-receives-404-error/32750/2

And I am also using the static build pack as well as the nodejs buildpack. please help !! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error has been solved by hosting my files on aws s3 and using that object url in my gltf loader. Make sure to set your CORS correctly

Answer (score 1):

There is a tiny issue with your path to the glTF asset. Instead of:

```js
loader.load('./Neo.glb', (gltf) => {
```

you want to use:

```js
loader.load('./model/Neo.glb', (gltf) => {
```

Comment: I just tried this file path out, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me Mr.Schrock did you run the NPM and make sure to pass the variables through the selective bloom? I'd say using a component in layerville livewire would be your best option. However, I also think that if you call the function into the div, you can use a boolean to make an if else statement. Make sure that you use node to call your react for deployment. Throw some swift elements into the app for your jquery on Heroku or look thru your contributions in the branch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).